# appWidget appearanse in the screen is different in different phones

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have created a WiFi widget. Which will show the user wifi details and its state.
If i am changing the the layout format of my phone the appearance of the widget is changing.
I would like to know more about the **layout format**. From my android phone i am able choose three types of layout format that are 3 X 4, 4 X 4, and 5 X 4. I am posting my Widget layout below. I am sure that my widget wont appear in the same way for all the phones. How i could make it work with every phone.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:id="@+id/wifi_background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<ImageView
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:id="@+id/wifi_signal_strength"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/wifi_circle"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/toggle" />


        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:scaleType="matrix"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/wifi_square"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/togglenetwork"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                    >
                    <FrameLayout 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/wifi_status"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:ellipsize="marquee"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textSize="10sp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/wifi_on"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:ellipsize="marquee"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textSize="11sp"/>
                    </FrameLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/wifi_ip"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="7sp"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:ellipsize="marquee"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/wifi_mac"

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="7sp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```